Should the partition key be added to `PRIMARY KEY` or `ORDER BY` list in Clickhouse?
I'm trying to create a partitioned table in Clickhouse with:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS new_table (
  logging_day Date,
  sensor_name String,
  ts       DateTime
  ts_hour  DateTime MATERIALIZED toStartOfHour(ts),
)
ENGINE=MergeTree()
PARTITION BY logging_day
ORDER BY (sensor_name, ts_hour, ts)
PRIMARY KEY (sensor_name, ts_hour);

The table is partitioned by logging_day. From query performance perspective, does it still need be added to the ORDER BY or PRIMARY KEY lists like:
ORDER BY (logging_day, sensor_name, ts_hour, ts)
PRIMARY KEY (logging_day, sensor_name, ts_hour);

Which way will make the filtered queries faster, for example SELECT * FROM new_table WHERE logging_day = '2024-04-20' AND sensor_name = 'foo' AND ts_hour = '2024-04-20 13:00:00', with or without the partition key in the lists? Thanks.

Look
https://kb.altinity.com/engines/mergetree-table-engine-family/pick-keys/

Duplicate question and found answer here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/20654 Please close it.

The ORDER BY key controls the order of data on disk. The PRIMARY KEY controls the sparse index.
By default the PRIMARY KEY will be set to the ORDER BY key - it builds the sparse index and loads it into memory for the columns in the key.
However, you can set the PRIMARY KEY to a prefix of the ORDER BY.
When would you do this?
When you want the compression of specifying a full ORDER BY but don't expect to query on the PRIMARY KEY latter entries - you save the memory of loading the index for these columns. Its rare but there are cases in use cases like ReplacingMergeTree and some access patterns.
In general, you don't need it.

In most cases, partitioning by month is sufficient. Overly granular partitioning, can lead to inefficiencies.
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS new_table (
logging_day Date,
sensor_name String,
ts DateTime,
ts_hour DateTime MATERIALIZED toStartOfHour(ts)
) ENGINE = MergeTree()
PARTITION BY toYYYYMM(logging_day)  -- Coarser partitioning by month
ORDER BY (logging_day, sensor_name, ts_hour)
PRIMARY KEY (logging_day, sensor_name, ts_hour);

This approach reduces the number of partitions and aligns with ClickHouse's best practices.
This ordering still respects the finer-grained needs of your queries without overly complicating the partitioning.
